# Getting error with Apache POI which is not able to read file passed using FileInputStream

Tags: java, apache-poi

While executing below code,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\deepa\\Downloads\\TestDocument.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

I am getting error as

```
InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
```

I have included all the apace poi jar files and common -compress jar file.
Please help.

Comment: Apache POI 4.0.0 needs commons-compress 1.18

Comment: I have added that also. Even after including that,  I am getting error

Comment: Could you doublecheck your setup? You are not the first person to hit this issue but it is caused by not having the up to date commons-compress jar. - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html

Comment: I have the latest jar fies- commons-compress-1.18 and apache POI 4.0.0

Comment: It's not enough to have the new jar, you also need to *not have* an older one! Check your classpath and remove old commons compress jars you find

Comment: See...Earlier I did not have common -compress jar file. After execution , I got the exception for missing class in common-compress. When I added the jar file and executed the script, I got the error mentioned in the question

Comment: You are sure you have got `Apache Commons Compress` version `1.18` and not version `1.8` or `1.8.1`? You need version `1.18`. `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream` implements `InputStreamStatistics` since version `1.17`.

Comment: Have downlaoded from this link :-https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/download_compress.cgi

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: No solution because your error is not reproducible. As said [ZipArchiveInputStream of version 1.18](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.18/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html) implements `InputStreamStatistics`. So if the error occurs, there **must** be an older version of `ZipArchiveInputStream` somewhere in the class path.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm also stuck with the same issue, I have commons-compress 1.18

Answer (score 0):

Not a java expert of any sorts, but I use Selenium for test automation and was also getting this error. Somehow I found a solution:

1. Open the .classpath file with a file editor.
2. Cut your classpathentry that contains commons-compress-1.18.jar and paste it at the beginning below classpathentry `kind="con"path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"`
3. Save and retry your program.

It solved my problem. Sorry I can't explain why (I am not a real programmer).